# Correct mistakes in a python program dealing with CSV

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to edit a CSV file using informations from a first one. That doesn't seem simple to me as I should filter multiple things. Let's explain my problem.

I have two CSV files, let's say patch.csv and origin.csv. Output csv file should have the same pattern as origin.csv, but with corrected values.

I want to replace trip_headsign column fields in origin.csv using forward_line_name column in patch.csv if direction_id field in origin.csv row is 0, or using backward_line_name if direction_id is 1.

I want to do this only if the part of the line_id value in patch.csv between ":" and ":" symbols is the same as the part of route_id value in origin.csv before the ":" symbol.

I know how to replace a whole line, but not only some parts, especially that I sometimes have to look only part of a value.

Here is a sample of origin.csv:

```
route_id,service_id,trip_id,trip_headsign,direction_id,block_id

210210109:001,2913,70405957139549,70405957,0,
210210109:001,2916,70405961139553,70405961,1,
```

and a sample of patch.csv:

```
line_id,line_code,line_name,forward_line_name,forward_direction,backward_line_name,backward_direction,line_color,line_sort,network_id,commercial_mode_id,contributor_id,geometry_id,line_opening_time,line_closing_time

OIF:100110010:10OIF439,10,Boulogne Pont de Saint-Cloud - Gare d'Austerlitz,BOULOGNE / PONT DE ST CLOUD - GARE D'AUSTERLITZ,OIF:SA:8754700,GARE D'AUSTERLITZ - BOULOGNE / PONT DE ST CLOUD,OIF:SA:59400,DFB039,91,OIF:439,metro,OIF,geometry:line:100110010:10,05:30:00,25:47:00
OIF:210210109:001OIF30,001,FFOURCHES LONGUEVILLE PROVINS,Place Mérot - GARE DE LONGUEVILLE,,GARE DE LONGUEVILLE - Place Mérot,OIF:SA:63:49,000000   1,OIF:30,bus,OIF,,05:39:00,19:50:00
```

**Each file has hundred of lines I need to parse and edit this way.**
Separator is comma in my csv files.

Based on mhopeng answer to a previous question, I obtained that code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput
import sys

# first get the route info from patch.csv
f = open(sys.argv[1])
d = open(sys.argv[2])
# ignore header line
#line1 = f.readline()
#line2 = d.readline()
# get line of data
for line1 in f.readline():
    line1 = f.readline().split(',')
    route_id = line1[0].split(':')[1] # '210210109'
    route_forward = line1[3]
    route_backward = line1[5]
    line_code = line1[1]

# process origin.csv and replace lines in-place
    for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[2], inplace=1):
        line2 = d.readline().split(',')
        num_route = line2[0].split(':')[0]
# prevent lines with same route_id but different line_code to be considered as the same line    
        if line.startswith(route_id) and (num_route == line_code):
        if line.startswith(route_id):
            newline = line.split(',')
            if newline[4] == 0:
                newline[3] = route_backward
            else:
                newline[3] = route_forward
            print('\t'.join(newline),end="")
        else:
            print(line,end="")
```

But unfortunately, that doesn't push the right forward or backward_line_name in trip_headsign (always forward is used), the condition to compare patch.csv line_code to the end of route_id of origin.csv (after the ":") doesn't work, and the script finally triggers that error, before finishing parsing the file:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./GTFS_enhancer_headsigns.py", line 28, in 
    if newline[4] == 0:
IndexError: list index out of range

Could you please help me fixing these three problems?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should consider using the python [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html) instead of `split()`.

Out of experience , everything is much easier when working with csv files and the csv module.

This way you can iterate through the dataset in a structured way without the risk of getting index out of range errors.